# Update Salesforce data using Apps Script

Tags: integration, salesforce-id

[{"message":"The Id field should not be specified in the sobject data.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]
That's the error message. Any other way to do it? My Code:

```
function update() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var dataRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var data = getRowsData(sheet, dataRange,1);
  var runningLog = '<h1>Update Successful</h1><br>Updated following:<br><br>';
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    var payload =  JSON.stringify(
      {"Id" : data[i].id,
       "Name__c" : data[i].name,
       "Email__c" : data[i].email,
       "Ex_Id__c" : data[i].exid
      }
    );
    var getDataURL = getRestEndpoint()+"/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/"+getWhichObject()+"/";
    runningLog += UrlFetchApp.fetch(getDataURL,getUrlFetchPATCHOptions(payload)).getContentText();
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(runningLog));
}
function getUrlFetchPATCHOptions(payload){
  var token = getSessionId();
  return {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : payload,
    "headers" : {
      "Authorization" : "OAuth " + token
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [POST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm) is used to insert a record and in that case the ID will be assigned once the record is inserted and so can't be specified.

A [PATCH](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm) is used to update an existing record identified by the ID supplied. It sounds like that is what you want so change:

```
"method": "post"
```

to:

```
"method": "patch"
```

**PS**

As identified by orsan in the comments below and listed at the end of the Salesforce [PATCH](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm) documentation, there is a workaround for libraries that don't support PATCH:

> If you use an HTTP library that doesn't allow overriding or setting an
>   arbitrary HTTP method name, you can send a POST request and provide an
>   override to the HTTP method via the query string parameter
>   _HttpMethod.

Comment: I tried it as well. The error message this time is: Message details
Attribute provided with invalid value: method

Comment: @orsan Sounds like UrlFetchApp.fetch or something it calls doesn't like the method value you are passing. Take a look at that code.

Comment: @orsan Looks like a known issue with some workarounds (worth trying but not guaranteed to work) listed here https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1224.

Comment: var getDataURL = getRestEndpoint()+"/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/"+getWhichObject()+"/"+data[i].id+"?_HttpMethod=PATCH";

Comment: It works now, with this update in the code.

Comment: @orsan Cool. Pity PATCH is often badly supported.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this issue when I try to update a record through client.UpdateAsync method in my asp.net mvc application.

I just made id property null before calling client.UpdateAsync and it worked.

```
[object].Id = null;
client.UpdateAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error using the **UpdateAsync(string objectName, string recordId, object record);** method of the [Force.com Toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) with the Salesforce REST API, the Id of the object being passed in as the third paramter of the method call needs to be null.  See example.

```
var id = contact.Id;
contact.Id = null;
var response = await _binding.UpdateAsync("Contact", id, contact);
```

Hope this helps!